# Opensource audio editor for Windows with export 8kHZ a-law capability

Tags: audio, audio-conversion

I cant find an opensource audio editor that allows me to export to 8khz a-law for IVR creation, google only brings up dross of crippled shareware apps.

Any recommendations? Primarily all i want to do is go from 44khz wav on windows 8 to 8khz/16-bit wav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Audacity?

Here you can set the resample rate and export it as Wav.

[image]

[image]